# line.split('/') giving new line on print?

Tags: python, parsing, text, split

Once i parse a text file using `x, y = line.split('/')`, whenver I print out `y` it does a new line.. This does not happen with `x`. When I attempt to concatenate a string after `y` it appears on the line below it.

I have attempted using rstrip('\n') with no luck

Edit:

```
print(Fore.GREEN + x +"  "+ y + " Success!" + Style.RESET_ALL)
```

what gets printed:

```
0.39281  0.38921
 Success!
```

when i am wanting for it to print

```
0.39281  0.38921 Success!
```

this doesn't only happen on print, this happens when writing to a text file also.

Comment: Can you include example code, input and expected/actual output?

Comment: @PedrovonHertwig Edited the post

Comment: can you try `y.rstrip()` instead?

Comment: @Tiny.D I have tried y.rstrip() and have obtained the same problem as before

Comment: share the `line` pls.

Comment: @Stackoverflower Can you include the value of the variable  `line` ?

Comment: @Tiny.D It's simply iterating line by line in a text file parsing data:
`with open(myFile) as file:
for line in file:
x, y = line.split('/')`

Comment: @Stackoverflower Try `string = Fore.GREEN + x +"  "+ y + " Success!" + Style.RESET_ALL; print(string.replace('\n', ' '));`

Comment: Actually I would much rather recommend you did `x, y = line.rstrip().split('/')`

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ both of those worked! Thank you!!

Comment: @Stackoverflower Yup, glad to help. Use the second one, it's more pythonic. Cheers.